# Remove one view's layout constraints but keep its subviews'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, constraints

Working on a project in iOS 8 using storyboard and auto layout:

1. In storyboard, specified constraints for this view and its subviews
2. In code, in response to touch events, I'm going to change this view's size by setting its frame

To make both 1 and 2 warning free, I'm doing the following when first changing its size with code:

```
[theView removeConstraints:theView.constraints];
theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
theView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);
```

If not doing the first line, Xcode will complain a whole bunch about constraint conflicts, however adding this line will remove all its subview's constraints as well. So my question is: is there way to just remove this uiview's constraints but not its subview, say a button on it still wants to center its self relative to this view's size and position?

Comment: Why do you need to change theView's size by setting its frame? I think the "proper" way to avoid the problems you're describing would be to add IBOutlets for the size constraints of theView as they're set in the storyboard, and then modify those constraints in code.

Comment: I'm doing this and it removes warnings when running the code, however now in storyboard, layout guide (dashed lines) warnings shows up, and if "update frames", its subviews will be out of place. Probably I'm just too OCD on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to resize the view by setting frame otherwise what is the point of keeping the constraint at first place. You could have position that by simply having a correct initial frame.

Secondly, you have a mis-conception about "TO-WHOM" a constraint has been applied to.

> say a button on it still wants to center its self relative to this view's size and position?

When you apply a position related constraint to a view you normally apply it to it's `superview`. Means if you want to position a `subview` in the horizontal centre of a `view` then the constraint is added on `view` not on the `subview`. That's why when you called a `removeContraints:` message on view that position constraint was removed and now your subview isn't bound to any constraint. However the width and height constraints are applied to subviews itself.

To solve this you need to make `IBOutlets` for constraint that you need to modify, which in your case should be width, height, horizontal x and top constraint; and then change the constant values for them respectively.

```
theView.widthConstraint.constant = newValue;
```

Comment: Indeed, I have the mis-conception mentioned here, and now it's clarified :). Since I'm only changing height, IBOutlet-ed it and it works. Thanks!